# How to use approve and delegate transfer tokens

Tags: web3.js

```
let that = this;
                let from_pubkey = new PublicKey('CXoqEjgAQrq4nQsP2YhFeh5Fi8nYY5jy2GAtsVkqao6i');
                let to_pubkey = new PublicKey('Exrb1iprXcRZcjyyaCj62onZnEbkJR6QLP6EdLMGw1Mx');
                let mint_pubkey = new PublicKey("Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB");
                let to_account = await that.get_solana_account(to_pubkey, mint_pubkey); //receiver
                let from_account = await that.get_solana_account(from_pubkey, mint_pubkey); //sender
                let token_instance = new Token(connection, mint_pubkey, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, from_pubkey);
                let transaction = new Transaction();
                let signer_pubkey = new PublicKey(window.solana.publicKey.toBase58())
                let signer_account = await that.get_solana_account(signer_pubkey, mint_pubkey); //signer
                transaction.add(
                    Token.createTransferInstruction(
                        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                        from_account.address,// sender account address
                        to_account.address,// to account address
                        new PublicKey(from_account.delegate.toBase58()),// sender delegate address
                        [new PublicKey(from_pubkey.toBase58())],
                        Math.pow(10,6) * 2
                    )
                );
                transaction.feePayer = signer_pubkey;
                transaction.recentBlockhash = (
                    await connection.getRecentBlockhash()
                ).blockhash;
                const signedTransaction = await window.solana.signTransaction(transaction)
                const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize())
                if (signature) {
                    console.log("success", signature);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Transfer function.

```
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
         Token.createTransferInstruction(
             TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
             fromTokenAccount.address,
             toTokenAccount.address,
             publicKey, // delegate address
             [],
             0
         )
     )
```

Comment: This method is to transfer out your own token,, but I want to transfer someone else's token

Comment: I need your help

Comment: After get the approval, you can run the transfer function with the delagated address

Comment: I don't understand,Can you provide a sample code

Comment: I just started learning solana

Comment: transaction.add(
     Token.createTransferInstruction(
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      from_token_account.address,// sender account address
      to_token_account.address,// to account address
      from_token_account.delegate,// sender delegate address
      [],
      5
     )
    );

Comment: How to obtain a delegate address,

Comment: fromTokenAccount.delegate  or other

Comment: If the signer is not the delegate account, you can't run the transaction.

Comment: Could you give me the code, please

Comment: ``` transaction.add(
     Token.createTransferInstruction(
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      from_account.address,// sender account address
      to_account.address,// to account address
      from_account.delegate,// sender delegate address
      [],
      Math.pow(10,6) * 1
     )
    );
    transaction.feePayer = signer_pubkey;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (
     await connection.getRecentBlockhash()
    ).blockhash;
    const signedTransaction = await window.solana.signTransaction(transaction) ```

Comment: Signature verification failed